# Output left or right when a condition is met within a php foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop with 2 options.

"Image and text" OR "plain text"

When the user selects "Image and text" the sections need to alternate image left and image right. I can achieve this using css `:nth-of-type`. But this only works if the image and text blocks are consecutive.

What I need to do is check which type of section the user has selected, if it's "image and text" add a class to define the layout and do the opposite for the next section that is also "image and text"

confused? me too... Heres some html to show how the sections should flow for a better understanding:

```html
<div class="image-text left"></div>
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="image-text right"></div>
```

This is my current PHP loop:

```php
<?php  
global $prefix;
$career_profiles = rwmb_meta("career_profiles");

foreach ( $career_profiles as $profile ) :

    $career_section = isset( $profile["{$prefix}career_section"] ) ? $profile["{$prefix}career_section"] : '';
    /**
     * Careers section can be image and text OR text
     * @var [type]
     */
    $career_section_class = ( $career_section == 'image_text' ) ? 'image-text' : 'text';

    $career_image = isset( $profile["{$prefix}career_image"] ) ? $profile["{$prefix}career_image"] : array();
    foreach ( $career_image as $ci ) :
        $photo = RWMB_Image_Field::file_info( $ci, array( 'size' => 'careers_photo' ) );
    endforeach;

    $career_name = isset( $profile["{$prefix}career_name"] ) ? $profile["{$prefix}career_name"] : '';
    $career_name_id = clean($career_name);
    $career_introduction = isset( $profile["{$prefix}career_introduction"] ) ? $profile["{$prefix}career_introduction"] : '';
?>

    <div class="<?php echo $career_section_class; ?> clearfix">
        <?php if ($photo) : ?>
            <div class="image b-lazy" data-src="<?php echo $photo['url']; ?>"></div><!-- /.image -->
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="profile clearfix">
            <div class="profile-wrapper font22 clearfix">
                <?php if ($career_name) : ?>
                    <h2 class="font34"><?php echo $career_name; ?></h2>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo wpautop($career_introduction); ?>
            </div><!-- /.profile-wrapper -->
        </div><!-- /.profile -->
    </div><!-- /.career-profiles_profile -->



<?php
endforeach; // foreach ( $career_profiles as $section ) :
?>
```

One thought I had was to check if the current loops `$career_section_class == 'image-text'` then add the `left` or `right` class, but how would I check in which order to add that positioning class?

Comment: Why not just put the class name into a variable, `$align = 'left';` - and whenever you encounter one of those image-and-text sections, you simply toggle it to `right`, resp. `left` again …

Comment: @04FS I'm not sure how to do the toggle.

Comment: @Aaron `$align = $align == "left" ? "right" : "left";`

Comment: @Barmar Is it that simple!  So to be clear, the $align variable class is set within the loop, then updated if it's already set to alternate the classes. OMG that's awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's really that simple. Then you simply substitute the value of the variable into the `class` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) and [@04FS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10955263/04fs) for their help in solving this.

For anybody else here is the solution:

```
$align = "";
foreach ( $career_profiles as $profile ) :


    $career_section = isset( $profile["{$prefix}career_section"] ) ? $profile["{$prefix}career_section"] : '';
    $career_section_class = ( $career_section == 'image_text' ) ? 'image-text' : 'text';

    /**
     * Alternate the class if the section == image_text
     */
    if ($career_section_class == 'image_text') {
        $align = $align == "left" ? "right" : "left";
    }


endforeach; // foreach ( $career_profiles as $section ) :
```